# what will be the average value of puLse train?

Tags: signal, signal-theory

[image: gfg]

I calculated it by $$I_{av} =\frac{\int_{T_i}^{T_i+T_h}Idt}{\int _{0}^{T_i+T_h}dt }$$
but the answer is different

---

the questions[image: dkkld]
actually I am trying to calculate average current through $C_1$, if there is application at the input of frequency f_i and the time for which one shot is active is Th ,hence we get a pulse train like above from the capacitor

---

Book text

[image: biok]

Comment: Its a little absurd to write integral of zero

Answer (score 1):

This answer was given before the OP changed his mind about what the question is.

> what will be the average value of puse train?

[image]

Average current is \$I_{PEAK}\times \dfrac{T_h}{T_h+T_i}\$ by visual inspection.

Comment: check question now

Comment: The average current through a capacitor inevitably is zero so your question appears to have got more absurd.

Comment: I added text in the book hope it can help in understanding better

Comment: I'll restate: The average current through a capacitor is zero. This is the long-term average based on the voltage not continually ramping up in one direction over the measurement period.

Comment: In book it is long term average?

Comment: I don't know because I haven't got the book.

Comment: I pasted the book text above

Comment: My answer remains the same. Average current through a capacitor (C1 as you specifically said) is zero (given the constraints I mentioned before). If you are asking something else then I can't tell that.